# Retrieving the text from an EditText

Tags: java, android

So I am making a little app where it takes a comma separated list and returns a random word in that list and I am having trouble getting the text from the `EditText` view.

I saw on Stackoverflow that you're suppose to use the `EditText.getText().toString()` methods in order to get the text from the `EditText`. However, when I use those method, the app stops working. I ran the debugger and my Input variable refers to an empty string and I also get an error that there is no local submit variable.

This is the java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText UserInput;
    Button reset;
    Button Submit;
    TextView result;
    String Input;
    String Result;
    String word;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserInput);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Reset);
        Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Choose);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);
        Input = UserInput.getText().toString();
        Result = "Your choice should be:";

        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Random random = new Random();
            String[] List = Input.split(",");
            int num = random.nextInt(List.length - 1);
            word = List[num];
            Result = Result + word;
            result.setText(Result);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the `EditText` view of the activity:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/UserInput"
    android:layout_width="273dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Choice A, Choice B, Choice C,..."
    android:inputType="text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Instructions" />
```

For example, if I write in the `EditText` 'a,b', I expect Input to be 'a,b' but it is not. When I was debugging, it showed me it was an empty string and I do not know why. Also. I got another error that there is no local submit variable in the `onClick` method. How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Post logcat error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `Input = UserInput.getText().toString();` inside the `onClick` method.

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Input = UserInput.getText().toString();
        Random random = new Random();
        String[] List = Input.split(",");
        int num = random.nextInt(List.length - 1);
        word = List[num];
        Result = Result + word;
        result.setText(Result);
    }
}
```

You need to read the `EditText` only when the button is clicked, not when the app first starts.

Layman's explanation:
In your current code, you read the `EditText` when the app is launched. Since it is empty at the time, you get an empty string when you read it.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the text from `EditText` at the time of declaring because of which `Input` is null. `Input` is **not watching** the edittext for change in its content.

To do this, you have to get Input again, just before submitting.

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Input = UserInput.getText().toString();
    if (Input != null) {
        String[] List = Input.split(",");
        int num = random.nextInt(List.length - 1);
        word = List[num];
        Result = Result + word;
        result.setText(Result);
    }        
    }
});
```

Comment: Side note suggestion, in JAVA it's preferable to start variable names with small letters. To be precise camelCase

Answer (score 0):

*Debugger shows empty string* in such case, `num` may become 0, which then can cause `IndexOutOfBounds` Exception.

```
String[] List = Input.split(",");
int num = random.nextInt(List.length - 1);
word = List[num];
```

Post your logcat for further assistance.